# Web-app project design App does not update automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-boot, web-applications

I want to monitor the status of an inventory that has 20 compartments. 
Each compartment can have one of the next 4 status:

-Error

-Empty

-RawMaterial

-Finished product

Graphically I represent the inventory it in a matrix of boxes(each box is one compartment) and I want to change the color of each box depending on the status of the compartment.

I need to simulate the monitoring of data and I am doing it by creating a random number from 0 to 3.

I also want to show a drop down alert section in the case of Error or if the inventory needs to be filled again or retire finished product.

Which is the best way to create this web app?

Currently, I am working with a spring boot project with gradle.

and do the design with html and css and do the logic with a javascript file. and show it in a webApp.

1. When I bootRun the app it is not updating automatically.
2. My random timer does not work.
3. I want to show an dropdown alert section in case I have an error, how do you
   sugest me to do it?
4. Maybe I should not use a spring application,what do you recommend?

I have the next code in JS, the timer function does not work.

```
var compartmentStatus = setInterval(monitor,5000);


function main() {
var a=10;
var b=1;

    for (var i=0;i<=3; i++){

    }
    switch (compartmentStatus){
        case 0:
            $('#11').css("background-color","#888888");
            break;
        case 1:
            $('#11').css("background-color","yellow");
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#11').css("background-color","green");
            break;
        case 3:
            $('#11').css("background-color","red");
            break;
    }
}


function monitor() {
    console.log("a");
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
}


$(document).ready(main);
```